# SharePoint ToC script - changing link style to headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on online SharePoint site, where I want to have Table of Contents on my pages. It went successful, but I'm not satisfied with links to headers, which are in this style: PageName#heading_[number], where I would like to have PageName#{headingName}.

Is it possible? Here is link to my script: https://pastebin.com/MVsJf0hr . I suppose that it must be written somewhere here:

`$(this).attr("id", "heading_" + i);
$("#theTOC").append("<a href='#heading_" + i + "' title='" + theLevel + "'>" + theLevelString + " " + $(this).text() + "</a><br />");`

Comment: Ok, I solved that problem by myself, if anyone curious how, here is code: https://pastebin.com/kg6wHzEV